# Linear Transformation over Subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, vector-spaces

Letting $F\subseteq K$ be fields, and $V$ a vector space over $K$.  Certainly, $V$ is also a vector space over $F$.  And if $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is a basis for $K$ over $F$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ a basis for $V$ over $K$, we can show that the set of $e_iv_j$ is a basis for $V$ over $F$.

Question:  If I have a transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ over $K$ whose matrix with respect to $\mathcal B$ has entries $a_{ij}$, how can I find a nice matrix representation over $F$ with respect to the basis defined above?  Certainly, there should be a nice way to order this induced basis to invoke a prettier block matrix type solution, but I'm having some trouble working out the details...

Answer (score 1):

Each entry of $T$ is a linear transformation $K \to K$ which is in particular $F$-linear, so can be expressed as a linear transformation over $F$ with respect to the basis $\{ e_1, ... e_n \}$. These are the blocks you want.

Comment: Ah, cool. But how do i express the $a_{ij}$ as transformations over $F$?  Certainly each is a linear combination of the $e_i$, but I don't  know where to go from there...

Comment: @AsinglePANCAKE: the same way as any other linear transformation. Look at what it does to a basis of $K$.

Comment: My ignorance shows through more and more.  So if I have $a_{11}= b_{11}e_1+...+b_{n1}e_n$ then applying this to $e_1$ gives me the vector $(b_{11}e_1,...,b_{n1}e_n)^T$ with respect to the basis for $K$.  This gives me an n by n block in place of each $ a{ij}$, but something feels pretty fishy still...(apologies, I'm on a bus on my phone)

Comment: No, applying this to $e_1$ gives $b_{11} e_1 e_1 + ... + b_{n1} e_n e_1$. Then you need to expand the products $e_i e_j$ in terms of the $e_i$.